# Are periodic decimal series self-asymptotic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, rational-numbers

If I understand correctly all sequences who converge towards a rational limit are self-asymptotic.
Example (dichotomy series):
$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{7}{8}, \frac{15}{16}, \frac{31}{32}, \frac{63}{64}...$
$\frac{3}{4}, \frac{7}{8}, \frac{15}{16}, \frac{31}{32}, \frac{63}{64}...$
$\frac{7}{8}, \frac{15}{16}, \frac{31}{32}, \frac{63}{64}...$

The difference between the sequences (which is basically the first one removing terms) is diminishing.

The same property exists for infinite non-periodic decimal series
e.g. $0.10111213141516....$
which can be approximated by the sequence:
$0.1, 0.10, 0.101, 0.1011, 0.10111, 0.101112 ....$
if we remove some terms the new sequence e.g.
$ 0.101112, 0.1011121, 0.10111213, 0.101112131 ....$

will be asymptotic to the above hence self-asymptotic.

What is not clear to me is if the periodic decimal series also holds this self-asymptotic property
E.g.
$0.363636363636....$
It seems to me that it is but I am not sure if we remove terms from the approximating sequence
I.e.
$0.36, 0.363, 0.3636, 0.36363, 0.363636....$
$0.3636, 0.36363, 0.363636....$

in the end they actually reach $0$ and do not converge in the way we define the convergence above.

Comment: For every real number $r$ , there exists a sequence of rational numbers converging to $r$. What exactly is the question ?

Comment: *Any* convergent series has the property that if you drop $k$ terms at the beginning, the difference between the new and old series tends to zero, simply because $s_{n+k}-s_n \to L - L = 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Whether the limit is rational or not (or the numbers in the sequence, for that matter) is irrelevant.

Comment: @Peter: The question is if the decimal periodic series is also self-asymptotic

Comment: @HansLundmark: So the decimal periodic series is self-asymptotic as well. My confusion is if the difference would not be infinitely diminishing but actually become $0$ hence it is not self-asymptotic

Comment: First a correction: I meant to write “any convergent **sequence**”, not series. Secondly, “asymptotic” ($(a_n) \sim (b_n)$) means $a_n/b_n \to 1$, which isn't the same thing as $a_n - b_n \to 0$ in general. But if $s_n \to L \neq 0$, then $s_n \neq 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, so we can divide by $s_n$, and $\frac{s_{n+k}}{s_n} - 1 = \frac{s_{n+k} - s_n}{s_n} \to \frac{L-L}{L} = 0$, so that indeed $\frac{s_{n+k}}{s_n} \to 1$ and hence $(s_{n+k}) \sim (s_n)$, and in this computation it doesn't matter if the **numerator** $s_{n+k} - s_n$ happens to be identically zero.

Comment: @HansLundmark:1) My understanding was that asymptotic means that the difference between $2$ sequences is evanescent i.e. constantly diminishing. Hence it would become as near to $0$ as we like for larger and larger values of $n$ in ${a_n}$. But with your definition, it seems that what I just wrote is wrong?

Comment: @HansLundmark: 2) In my example with $0.(36)$ it is indeed the case that $s_n \limit L \neq 0$. Then we again have $\frac{L-L}{L} = /frac{0.3636... - 0.363.....}{0.36....} = 0$ hence self asymptotic?

Comment: What I showed is that that the two statements mean the same thing *in this case*. But not in general, since for example $a_n=n^2+n$ is asymptotic to $b_n=n^2$, even though their *difference* tends to infinity. Anyway, I don't see what the problem is with the difference being zero. After all, the constant sequence $(0,0,0,\dots)$ *trivially* tends to zero!

Comment: @HansLundmark: Does this means that the definition I had in mind is not the one used in general? I can see that it does not hold in your example with $n^2 + n$ and $n^2$. Also since any infinite non-periodic and infinite periodic decimal series are both self-asymptotic then it means that both converge to a limit i.e. the real number?

Comment: The generally accepted definition of asymptotic equivalence is the one that I wrote. See here, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition, https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Asymptotic_equivalence. The second question I don't understand.

Comment: @HansLundmark: Basically I am trying to confirm that both infinite non-periodic and infinite periodic decimal series are self-asymptotic. I think they are but wanted to see if there are any caveats